# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) - Hetzner VPS (macOS)

Tags: ssh, permissions

(macOS) I set up a VPS at Hetzner (ubuntu 20.04), generated a ssh keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. I added the public key to the ssh section. I then tried to connect `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa x.x.x.x`, but i keep getting permission denied error  `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`. I have no problem connecting to an Oracle cloud instance the same way.

I tried disabling firewall, changing file permissions to my keys, pretty much everything i could find online.

My friend who also has access to this project is connecting with putty and is able to connect without any issues.

This is the verbose:

````
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/suchmax/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/suchmax/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to x.x.x.x:22 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/suchmax/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:8iUxxxxxU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/suchmax/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/suchmax/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/suchmax/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lW/x/x/x/x/x explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/suchmax/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lW/x/x/x/x/x explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). ```
````